# repeat tickerText on the notification

Tags: android

Iam running  a service, this service downloading a file, and when it finish it notify the user via the notification bar.

so when there is a notification the user can see the tickerText, and then it disspear.

is there anyway of repeating this tickerText every X time on the notification line, until the user pulling the notification bar?

thanks,

Comment: Have you tried setting again and again the notification, it should ticker.

Comment: How would you best implement it, in the code with timing?

Comment: coz it's start to be very ugly with alarManager, i have to create new class which extends BroadcastReceiver, and move some code logic into there..and how will i trigger it to stop when the user open the notification bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there anyway of repeating this
>   tickerText every X time on the
>   notification line, until the user
>   pulling the notification bar?

The ticker text only appears when the `Notification` is added. If you notice, the ticker text eliminates all other icons, including the signal strength and such. Having that be gone perpetually, or even periodically, will be aggravating to users who do not want to deal with your `Notification` right this second.

Comment: Yes, i understand it could be annoying. and i know how much you are sensitive about user-enviroument:) but if you had to scheduale this.. or any other logic, how would you do it?(you are under the scope of service)